# How gauss law is not applicable here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law

I am a high school student and I am very confused in how to use Gauss law, when we have to calculate electric field due to infinite sheet or wire, and for spherical surfaces, I know how we do that, we select any point nearby the sheet because at nearby points  the components of electric field along that sheet will cancel out and components of electric field perpendicular to that area are almost the same as sheet is infinite(means the selected area is very small as compared to that of sheet) so we directly apply the gauss law here and calculate the electric field

but my confusion is that  if we want to calculate electric field  at any point along the line passing through the center of the sheet, so even if the sheet is finite and the point is not near, as far as we have chosen very small area about that point why we cannot do that? we know the direction of electric field on that line will be along the line ,so we know the direction is perpendicular to the chosen small area and also we have chosen very small area so we can assume electric field to be constant throughout the area, so why we cannot directly apply it here? yes, for points other than center we don't know the direction of field and also electric field is not parallel to the curved surface area of chosen cylinder we cannot do that, but for center why it still gives the incorrect answer even though it is perfectly symmetrical(yes of course it is not that much perfect as if the point is near but still very very less change in angles and distance from all sides occurs(I have seen it numerically by plotting the graphs of angles with distance)

[image: this image is a rough diagram which is showing that even though we take distant point at the line passing through center symmetry still remains as it is]

Comment: +1 for using "confusion" instead of "doubt"

Comment: "*and the point is far,*" is this a typo?

Comment: @DKNguyen [doubt is very common in Indian English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294125/indian-english-what-usage-is-allowed-for-doubt-meaning-question)

Comment: @AkshatSharma I know it is. That's exactly why I am giving the +1.

Answer (score 0):

When we say Gauss's Law is applicable for infinite bodies it implies that Gauss's Law can be applied only to find electric field at a point from where the body appears to us to be infinitely large.This distance is only a few atomic radii for a rod.If you are at a larger distance from the rod you will be able to see the ends of the finite rod so the rod will no longer appear infinite to you and we will no longer be able to use Gauss's Law from this point onwards.

Comment: I think OP is asking why the ends, being symmetrical, don't cancel out their perpendicular contributions even if they are visible.

Comment: They do cancel out their perpendicular components but the horizontal component of any elemental charge at any point are different and depend on the position of the elemental charge so integration is the only option.

Comment: That might be the part the OP Is looking for. If OP is in high-school they might not know about integration and are just using pre-calculated "canned" equations where the integration has already been done for the three scenarios presented to them

Comment: Yeah that's a possibility

Comment: "They do cancel out their perpendicular components but the horizontal component of any elemental charge at any point are different and depend on the position of the elemental charge so integration is the only option." but if we had chosen very small area why can't we say that at each point in that area electric field is almost same? like we have said when pointsa are near?

Comment: so why we can't directly (without integration) calculate the electric field at a point on the axis passing through the center?

Comment: my confusion is simply that for near points we treat the electric field at any point to be the same because as sheet is infinite the situation is symmetrical for all points near the sheet but even if the point is far but on the axis passing through the center then why we cannot choose a small area around that point and say that electric field can be assumed to be constant in that very small area so we can directly(without integration use the gauss law and calculate the electric field at that point? what kind of assymetry is occuring here?